# Ruby on Rails: DRYing a repeated code block that initializes a few variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I've got a repeated code block that initializes a few variables in a bunch of different controller methods. Is there a way for me to make this DRY with a model method as opposed to repeating the same code block in each controller method?

Basically, it's for a social site, and it's pulling up a user's list of friends, and then building buckets of friends based on the permissions the user has which are stored in a friendship model. This repeated initialization of buckets is what I'm trying to make DRY.

Normally I would use a model method, but in this case, 3 separate variables are being initialized based on one database pull, and this is called often enough I don't want to make it unnecessarily inefficient by hitting the database 3 times. In C, I would just use pointers passed in as variables.

It goes something like this:

```
def example_method
  friendships = @user.friendships
  view_permission_friends = []
  write_permission_friends = []
  message_permission_friends = []
  for friendship in friendships
    if friendship.view_permission then view_permission_friends << friendship.friend_id end
    if friendship.write_permission then write_permission_friends << friendship.friend_id end
    if friendship.message_permission then message_permission_friends << friendship.friend_id end
  end
  #Do something with the 3 initialized arrays here
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about it for a bit, and I think this code should go into your User model. (Or whatever class @user is in your example above.) Two reasons:

1. It's very specific to the User, its relationships, and most importantly, how they're stored in and retrieved from the database.
2. You only need to write the code once: in the User model.

The quick and easy way which relies on Rails' internal query caching would look like this. Added into the User model:

```
def view_permission_friends
  return friendships.select{|f| f.view_permission}
end

(etc.)
```

Your controllers then simply do this:

```
@viewers = @user.view_permission_friends
(etc.)
```

(Note - there's more room for optimization and better flexibility here via lazy caching and parameterizing the permission.)

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
rv = {}
%w(view write message).each do |type|
  rv["#{type}_permission_friends"] = @user.friendships.select{|f|f.send(:"#{type}_permission")}.collect(&:friend_id)
end
```

This gives you a hash with keys instead of individual arrays, but should suffice.

Comment: I think I might have been unclear in my question, which I've revised. I'm trying to DRY out the repeated use of this entire block in each controller method, rather than optimize the block itself. I'm okay with splitting the array building into separate lines. Though you're right, if I were to return a hash from a model method, that would enable me to just stick the arrays in the hash. Is that the best way to do this though?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003129), [`Enumerable#find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003124) and [`Object#instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000368):

```
def example_method
  %w{view write message}.inject({}) do |memo, s|
    friendships = @user.friendships.find_all{ |f| f.send("#{s}_permission") }
    memo["#{s}_permission_friends"] = friendships
  end.each do |key, value|
    instance_variable_set "@#{key}", value
  end

  # now you have 3 arrays:
  # @view_permission_friends, @write_permission_friends and @message_permission_friends
end
```